# File uploads, but data doesn't enter the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

So, I have a page I'm working on where I want to upload a file, then save the file name, as well as a couple more things to the database. The file ends up being saved to the server, but the filename, "label" and "section" don't get inserted in to the database. Here is the code-behind:

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtDocLabelText = (TextBox)Formview1.FindControl("DocLabelText");
    DropDownList ddlSection = (DropDownList)Formview1.FindControl("DropDownList1");
    FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)Formview1.FindControl("FileUpload1");
    Label UploadStatusLabel = (Label)Formview1.FindControl("UploadStatusLabel");

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/doc" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "appl/text" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.msword" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-word" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/winword" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/word" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/msword" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/x-msw6" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/x-msword" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/pdf" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/x-pdf" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template"
                )
            {
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400000)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/docs/HRDocs/") + filename);
                    UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Complete!";
                    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\[database name];";
                    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO Docs (Filename, Label, Section) VALUES (?,?,?)";

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

                    con.Open();
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Filename", filename);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Label", txtDocLabelText.Text);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", ddlSection.SelectedValue);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                else
                    UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 100 MB!";
            }
            else
                UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only JPEG files are accepted!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

And here is the markup:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/[database name]" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Docs] WHERE [ID] = ?" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Docs] ([Filename], [Label], [Section]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Docs]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Docs] SET [Filename] = ?, [Label] = ?, [Section] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Filename" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Label" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Section" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Filename" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Label" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Section" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>

<asp:FormView ID="Formview1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" >
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="DocLabelLabel" runat="server" Text="What is the label? (can only be Word or PDF documents):" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="DocLabelText" runat="server" Columns="100" /><br /><br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="Section" 
            DataValueField="Section">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="UploadStatusLabel" runat="server" Text="Status: " /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" OnClick="UploadFile" Text="Insert Item" /><br />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView><br />
```

Again, all that happens is that the file gets uploaded to the server, but the information doesn't get put into the database. I have a gridview control further down the page that displays the info from the database, but it doesn't even get into the database for the gridview to show it.

Comment: are you using an access database?

Comment: I am. Does that matter?

Comment: Have you set a break point and stepped through the code? Isolating the exact line that is failing can help you find a resolution.

Comment: Yeah, When I do the breakpoints, my variable "filename" indeed has the filename stored in it, but when I step to "com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", ddlSection.SelectedValue)" it just has "{System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox}" as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .ToString() to capture the drop down list value. Also, capture the value before passing the parameter to make it easier to debug.

```
string section = ddlSection.SelectedValue.ToString();
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", section);
```

If you are still not capturing the drop down list value when using .ToString(), then you might be having a postback issue and can use PreRender to capture the value. See this link for information on how to use PreRender: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/191898/DropDownList-and-capturing-values-after-SelectedIn